# break new line horizontal scrollable menu arrangement, css

Tags: css

I have this menu that shows a set of colors for the user to pick...

**PROBLEM**

I want to break a ne linew after the `li` number 23....

I tried to use a class `.breaker` that uses `clear:both;  display:block` but it only move this single element downwards..

How can I get this?

```css
.BgPickerMenu {
position: relative;
 width:300px!important;
 overflow:hidden;
    height: 80px;
 background:#fff;
 margin:50px auto 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.BgPickerScroll {
white-space: nowrap;
position: relative;
overflow:auto;  
font-size:0; 
border: 0px solid blue;
}

.BgPickerScroll li{
display:inline-block;
text-align:center; 
cursor:pointer;
font-size:12px;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
border: 1px solid #E1E8ED;
}

.BgPickerScroll::-webkit-scrollbar{
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  background: transparent;
}

.Breaker{
 clear:left;display:block!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="BgPickerMenu">
<ul class="BgPickerScroll">
<li class="Order Color1"></li>
<li class="Order Color2"></li>
<li class="Order Color3"></li>
<li class="Order Color4"></li>
<li class="Order Color5"></li>
<li class="Order Color6"></li>
<li class="Order Color7"></li>
<li class="Order Color8"></li>
<li class="Order Color9"></li>
<li class="Order Color10"></li>
<li class="Order Color11"></li>
<li class="Order Color12"></li>
<li class="Order Color13"></li>
<li class="Order Color14"></li>
<li class="Order Color15"></li>
<li class="Order Color16"></li>
<li class="Order Color17"></li>
<li class="Order Color18"></li>
<li class="Order Color19"></li>
<li class="Order Color20"></li>
<li class="Order Color21"></li>
<li class="Order Color22"></li>
<li class="Order Color23 Breaker"></li>
<li class="Order Color24"></li>
<li class="Order Color25"></li>
<li class="Order Color26"></li>
<li class="Order Color27"></li>
<li class="Order Color28"></li>
<li class="Order Color29"></li>
<li class="Order Color30"></li>
<li class="Order Color31"></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding some padding?

```
.Break {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```